# Motion of uniform accelerating rocket in special relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, spacetime, rocket-science, relative-motion

I have been trying to learn more about acceleration in special relativity. For the purpose I consulted the great Lev Landau. He has an example about this in his book but one of his equations puzzles me. Consider a rocket accelerating in the positive $x$ direction.The four acceleration for an observer that sees the rocket moving at speed $v$ is given by

$$
a^{\mu}=\gamma \frac{d}{dt}(c\gamma,v\gamma) 
$$

In the instantaneous rest frame of the rocket where $v=0$, we have
$$
a^{\mu}=(0,a_0,0,0).
$$
This instantaneous frame I picture as the passengers of the rocket being pressed to their seats.

Then Landau claims that you could square the expressions for the two rest frames and obtain

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{v}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} = \frac{d}{dt}(\gamma v) = a
$$

The right hand side of this equation is clear, obviously it is the square of the four acceleration in the instantaneous rest frame. But how to get the right hand side from $a^{\mu}a_{\mu}$ in the system in which the rocket moves?
I would appreciate your help.

EDIT: 
Some Remarks
Written in an explicit form 
$$
a^{\mu}=\gamma^2\left(\frac{\textbf{v}\cdot \textbf{ a}}{c}\gamma ,\frac{\textbf{v}\cdot \textbf{a}}{c^2}\gamma v +\textbf{a } \right)
$$

Where 
$$
\frac{d\gamma}{dt}=\frac{\textbf{v}\cdot \textbf{ a}}{c^2}\gamma^3
$$

Along these lines

$$
a_{\mu}a^{\mu}=\frac{\left(\textbf{v}\cdot \textbf{ a}\right)^2}{c^2}\gamma^6 +\gamma^4a^2 = a_0^2
$$

with some vector algebra:
$$
a_{\mu}a^{\mu}=\frac{\left(\textbf{v}\cdot \textbf{ a}\right)^2}{c^2}\gamma^6 +\gamma^4a^2 = \gamma^6\left(\frac{a^2v^2-(\textbf{a}\times \textbf{v})^2}{c^2} \right)+\gamma^4a^2=a_0^2
$$
If $\textbf{a} \parallel \textbf{v}$ the above reduces to 
$$
a_{\mu}a^{\mu}= \gamma^6\left(\frac{a^2v^2}{c^2} \right)+\gamma^4a^2=a_0^2,
$$
which is different from what Landau has. I should be getting instead:
$$
**a_0=\gamma^3a**
$$

Answer:
$$
\gamma^6\left(\frac{a^2v^2}{c^2} \right)+\gamma^4a^2=\gamma^4a^2\left(1+\gamma^2\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)=\gamma^4a^2\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^1}}\right)=\gamma^6a^2
$$

Remark:
What is an instantaneous rest frame?

Consider a rocket which undergoes constant acceleration along $\hat{x}$. Although the velocity is changing, we consider a frame in which the rocket
is `instantaneously` at rest. In such a frame, the rocket’s 4-acceleration is $(0, a_0 )$. Which is a key concept for this problem.

Comment: If you are considering so-called "instantaneous rest frame", i.e. v=0, then there is no motion whatsoever, so what is the role of SR here? SR applies to situations, where there is not only a difference of speeds between two objects, but also this difference is ... well ... huge ...

Comment: @brightmagus I don't really understand what you are trying to say? This is a standard problem with two frames of reference.

Comment: I'm not **trying** anything. I said what I said: if the frames are not moving wrt. to each other (v=0), SR is not applicable. That's "standard" conclusion.

Comment: @brightmagus I think that you are getting confused how acceleration is treated in SR and what is instantaneous rest frame.

Comment: $\frac{v^2}{c^2}$ may be rewritten as $1-\frac{1}{\gamma^2}$. Try plugging that in.

Comment: @brightmagus I don't know where this conversation is heading. However, allow me the liberty to ask you, whether you know what an instantenious rest frame is? That is a central concept in relativity and without it you can't treat uniform acceleration. Perhaps this is causing the confusion. For more information check the book "Classical field theory" of L. D. Landau and E. M. Lifschitz where this problem originates from.

Comment: Exactly, Alexander Cska. I do not know where you are heading with your comments. I didn't ask you to examine me or recommend any reading. I made a simple comment taking note of an obvious fact. So  if you believe it is wrong than perhaps you would rather refer to the merits of what I wrote instead. Your remark that without the concept of instantaneous rest frame it is impossible to treat acceleration in SR is not very scientific actually.

Comment: @brightmagus instantaneous rest frame is written right at the beginning of my answer and what it result into for the 4-acceleration is expressed by a formula. Based on your comments you have clearly no idea what you are talking about and moreover you are not very friendly. Therefore, goodbye and have a nice day.

Comment: @AlexanderCska; I do not see any answer of yours here, only a question. Still, you apparently have no idea of basic physics concepts, such as velocity. Again, by definition, rest means there is no velocity at all (as you wrote yourself: $v=0$), and therefore you cannot actually apply any relativity equations for this "instant", because there is no relative movement whatsoever. So you have 2 possibilities in your case: either the time is frozen, which means nothing moves and SR doesn't apply, or the time flows, but then the rocket is accelerating and SR doesn't apply again. *Tertium non datur.*

Comment: By the way, not referring to the merits of the remark and speculating about its author is very unfriendly. And more importantly - not scientific ...

Comment: @brightmagus as I said read more about what instantaneous rest frame is and what it is used for SR and accelerated motion. You still don't get the point of the question and keep repeating the same wrong things.

Comment: @AlexanderCska, you are still not referring to my remark and keep giving me unsolicited advice. You do not like my comment and do not know how to respond properly? You can always ignore it without being rude ...

Comment: @brightmagus your remark is simply wrong. Check the information I gave you and just then come back for more comments. I am not being rude in any way, you just started derailing in some strange direction. In general, if you are not sure about something you should avoid commenting, because this can confuse other people.

Comment: @AlexanderCska, I am perfectly sure of what I said. Apparently you are not since you are not able to address my comment directly and dodge the problem by talking about me instead of the problem. Well-known yet lowly technique.

Comment: @brightmagus just relax. I think that the problem here is your misunderstanding of the equivalence principle. In the instantaneous (local) rest frame $a_{\mu}=(0,a,0,0)$ for a simple 1D case or in general  $a_{\mu}=(0,\mathbf{a})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your confusion is understandable, because Landau used the same symbol for the proper acceleration and the coordinate acceleration. What Landau actually claims is that in the observer frame
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(\gamma v) = a_0,
$$
where I used your notation $a_0 = \sqrt{a^\mu a_\mu}$. This quantity is a four-scalar (which means it is Lorentz invariant) and is called the *proper acceleration*. You correctly deduced that $a_0 = \gamma^3 a$ (if the acceleration is parallel to the velocity), where $a = dv/dt$ is the ordinary coordinate acceleration (which is *not* a four-scalar, and therefore depends on the reference frame). Landau then remarks that $a_0$ coincides with $a$ in the instantaneous rest-frame, since in that frame $v=0$ and $\gamma = 1$.

EDIT

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}(\gamma v) &= \frac{d\gamma}{dt}v + \gamma\frac{dv}{dt}\\
&= \frac{v/c^2}{(1 - v^2/c^2)^{3/2}}\frac{dv}{dt}v + \frac{1}{(1 - v^2/c^2)^{1/2}}\frac{dv}{dt}\\
&= \frac{v^2/c^2}{(1 - v^2/c^2)^{3/2}}a + \frac{1 - v^2/c^2}{(1 - v^2/c^2)^{3/2}}a\\
&= \frac{1}{(1 - v^2/c^2)^{3/2}}a = \gamma^3 a = a_0.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I don't really understand how to go from $a_0=\gamma^3a \to \frac{d}{dt}(v\gamma)=a_0$. I used $\gamma^3=\frac{d}{dv}(\gamma v)$, but still I have derivative with respect to $v$ and not $t$ as Landau has it. i.e  $a\frac{d}{dv}(\gamma v)=a_0$

Comment: @AlexanderCska I've added the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The product $a^\mu a_\mu$ can be written as $a^\mu a^\nu \eta_{\mu\nu}$. This metric (the Minkowski metric) usually carries the signature $(-,+,+,+)$ or $(+,-,-,-)$. Either way, the time coordinate has to have the opposite sign. The product here gives you some nice cancellations when you take the product of

$a^{\mu}=\gamma \frac{d}{dt}(c\gamma,u\gamma)$ --- (here $u$ is the four-velocity)

with itself, calculating the time derivative first, then doing very simple multiplications.

You'll get to a point where you have the dot product equal to the following:

$a^\mu a_\mu = a^2 \gamma_u^6$

Which when expanded using Taylor's Theorem to first order in $u$ gives simply

$a^\mu a_\mu \approx a^2$, as $\gamma_u^6$ is very very small for even relativistic values of $u$.

Comment: @hebetudionus no this is wrong and there are no expansions needed. The expression in Landau-Lifschitz is a precise one!

Comment: You're right, if the value you're trying to find is $a_0 = a\gamma^3$. In my notebook it was from a problem where I had to show that $a_\mu a^\mu = a^2$. My mistake.